# How to built the blackberry project in eclipse using various OS version?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am using blackberry java plugin for eclipse for development & as i downloaded latest version of it.it comes with os version 7 but i want to built my application using os version 5,6 etc.but i am not having idea about it so is anybody can tell me how should i proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your pluging go to help->install new software, you will get a window in that you will find "work with" ....there paste this URL   **Blackberry upadates :  http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java**    there at the bottem selection box will displays ,there u can selet the JDKs. select your jdk ,then click finish...it will take some time time to down load.

Comment: It is taking very much time to get download .After some time it stops.Is there any another solution for that?

Comment: I think there is no alternate .....try it on fast internet.....it takes more than 30 mins.